# POST form to new window

Tags: javascript, html

I'm going to try my hardest to try and explain what I'm trying to achieve essentially what I'm after is for the form to POST to the `post_form_here.html` and then to redirect the main page to `redirect_main_page.html` I need the form to post the values to the popout window and then to redirect the main page to the redirect page.

```
 <form method="POST" onclick="window.open('POST_FORM_HERE.HTML', 'newwindow',
 'width=500,height=500');  return true;" action="REDIRECT_MAIN_PAGE.HTML">
```

This is what I have so far however this posts the form to the `redirect_main_page.html` and not the `post_form_here.html`. Thank-you for any help and I hope I've explained what I'm trying to achieve well enough.

Comment: Is it ok for you to use jquery?

Comment: @HarryBomrah yes :)

Comment: instead onclick write jquery function on for submit and using window.location redirect to particular page

Comment: I think to submit to a new form to open in in new window, you ve to use `GET` method. Is it ok? If you still want to use `POST` then you need to have a middle page to achieve this.

Comment: @HarryBomrah `GET` is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="name" >
    <input type="text" name="age" >
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JS

```
var form = $("#form");
form.on("submit",function(){
    window.open("POST_FORM_HERE.html?" + form.serialize(), "newwindow", 'width=500,height=500');
    window.location.href = "/REDIRECT_MAIN_PAGE.html";
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 3):

use target="_blank" in form

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get" target="_blank">    
</form>
```

If you want new window use like this

```
<form method="post" 
           target="new_popup" 
           action="https://www.google.co.in/" 
           onsubmit="window.open('about:blank','new_popup','width=500,height=300');">

        <input type="text" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: i.e. no need for JavaScript pop-ups.

Comment: I need the window to have a set width and height and not be in the same window as other tabs. it needs to be a popout window. plus there is two page destinations that need to be set.

Comment: Yes. no need javascript pop-ups @Utkanos

Comment: this is not the answer